# How to get rows by max date with certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the latest column when columns `I` and `II` are the same. 
So the result should be. `1/30/2017` beats out `1/27/2017`.

```
I I III                    IV
A X 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
A Y 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
A Z 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
A X 1/27/2017  4:53:00 PM  some_data
A Y 1/27/2017  4:53:00 PM  some_data
A Z 1/27/2017  4:53:00 PM  some_data
B X 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
B Y 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
B Z 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
B X 1/27/2017  4:53:00 PM  some_data
B Y 1/27/2017  4:53:00 PM  some_data
B Z 1/27/2017  4:53:00 PM  some_data
```

This is the result I want.

```
I I III                    IV
A X 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
A Y 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
A Z 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
B X 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
B Y 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
B Z 1/30/2017  9:33:00 AM  some_data
```

Can someone help me figure out how to extract these rows?

Comment: can you show some code which you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want is a`groupby()`, `transform()` and `max()`:

**Code:**

```
data = [
    ('I', 'II', 'III', 'IV'),
    ('A', 'X', '1/30/2017 9:33:00 AM', 'some_data'),
    ('A', 'Y', '1/30/2017 9:33:00 AM', 'some_data'),
    ('A', 'Z', '1/30/2017 9:33:00 AM', 'some_data'),
    ('A', 'X', '1/27/2017 4:53:00 PM', 'some_data'),
    ('A', 'Y', '1/27/2017 4:53:00 PM', 'some_data'),
    ('A', 'Z', '1/27/2017 4:53:00 PM', 'some_data'),
    ('B', 'X', '1/30/2017 9:33:00 AM', 'some_data'),
    ('B', 'Y', '1/30/2017 9:33:00 AM', 'some_data'),
    ('B', 'Z', '1/30/2017 9:33:00 AM', 'some_data'),
    ('B', 'X', '1/27/2017 4:53:00 PM', 'some_data'),
    ('B', 'Y', '1/27/2017 4:53:00 PM', 'some_data'),
    ('B', 'Z', '1/27/2017 4:53:00 PM', 'some_data'),
]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df['III'] = pd.to_datetime(df['III'])

# groupby first two columns, then get the maximum value in the third column
idx = df.groupby(['I', 'II'])['III'].transform(max) == df['III']

# use the index to fetch correct rows in dataframe
print(df[idx])
```

**Results:**

```
   I II                 III         IV
0  A  X 2017-01-30 09:33:00  some_data
1  A  Y 2017-01-30 09:33:00  some_data
2  A  Z 2017-01-30 09:33:00  some_data
6  B  X 2017-01-30 09:33:00  some_data
7  B  Y 2017-01-30 09:33:00  some_data
8  B  Z 2017-01-30 09:33:00  some_data
```